# How can I reverse the caption numbering in listing

Tags: listings, captions

How can I make a reverse numbered caption with listings? So the package makes ''Listing 1.1'' style captions but I need  it in form ''1.1 Listing'' .

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Remember that you can accept one of the answers below, since both seem to solve your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the »[caption](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption)« package to declare a new label format. Of course you can do other additional customizations in this way.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{reverse}{#2 #1}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{labelformat=reverse}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
  \chapter{Foo}

  \section{Bar}
    \begin{lstlisting}[
      gobble=6,
      frame=single,
      caption={Useless code},
      label=useless
    ]
      for i:=maxint to 0 do
      begin
        { do nothing }
      end;
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Without any additional package, add the following lines in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\fnum@lstlisting{%
  \ifx\lst@@caption\@empty\else\thelstlisting~\fi%
  \lstlistingname}%
\makeatother
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\fnum@lstlisting{%
  \ifx\lst@@caption\@empty\else\thelstlisting~\fi%
  \lstlistingname}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single,caption={foo}]
Welcome to TeX.SX
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]