# Reverse caption number and text order in special listing

Tags: listings, tcolorbox, minted

I would like to change the original `Listing 1.1: Caption` style to **`1.1. listing.`** *`Caption`*.

I've already found two possible solutions to this problem in the following thread:
[How can I reverse the caption numbering in listing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160718/how-can-i-reverse-the-caption-numbering-in-listing?newreg=9b405b82c62b42548b7c4172a6bb84b6). Unfortunately, none of them works for me. I suspect this is because the very specific way I am using listings.

Here is my config (that I created from lots of TexStackExchange posts) with a minimal working example.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}

\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage[english,magyar]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[chapter]{minted}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}                  % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305387/adding-a-caption-to-a-tcolorbox-tcblisting

\tcbuselibrary{listings,minted,skins,breakable}
\renewcommand*\thelstnumber{\ifnum\value{lstnumber}<10 0\fi\the\value{lstnumber}}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Kódrészlet}
\renewcommand{\listoflistingscaption}{Kódrészletek jegyzéke}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\fnum@lstlisting{%
  \ifx\lst@@caption\@empty\else\thelstlisting~\fi%
  \lstlistingname}%
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\let\c@listing\c@lstlisting}
\makeatother

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \newtcblisting[blend into=listings]{code}[3]{%
    breakable,
    colback=codebg,
    colframe=black!40,
    enhanced,
    listing engine=minted,
    listing only,
    left=5mm,
    overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[black!25] (frame.south west)
      rectangle ([xshift=5mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}},
    listing remove caption=false,
    minted style=colorful,
    minted language=#1,
    minted options={linenos=true,numbersep=3mm,texcl=true,breaklines=true,autogobble=true},
    coltitle=black,
    attach boxed title to bottom center={yshift=-10pt},
    boxed title style={enhanced jigsaw, colback=white, sharp corners, boxrule=0pt},
    #2
  }
}
\definecolor{codebg}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}

\newcommand{\listAref}[1]{\Aref{lst:#1}. kódrészlet}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents\vfill

\newpage
\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
  \begin{code}{swift}{title={Test title}, label={lst:test-code}}

    import Foundation
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

      override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

      }

    }

  \end{code}
\end{otherlanguage}

\listAref{test-code} egy tesztkódot mutat.

\listoflistings\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Kódrészletek jegyzéke}

\end{document}
```

Everything is working fine but the `fnum@lstlisting` seems to be ignored(?). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Instead of code fragments, it's better that you build a minimal but complete working or not example. From `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`. This way possible helpers won't have to imagine what kind of document are you compiling or what packages are you using.

Comment: @Ignasi thank you! I extended my question with a simple working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made two changes to treat the problem.

Firstly, an alternative to `blend into=listings` is constructed by

```
\tcbset{
  new/blend into/revlistings/.style={use counter*=lstlisting,list inside=lol,/tcb/code={\appto\tcb@new@colopt{,before title={\tcb@blend@beforetitle{\thetcbcounter~\lstlistingname}}}}},%
}
```

The new `blend into=revlistings` reverses the number with the name.

Secondly,

```
blend before title code={##1.\ },
```

is added to exchange the `:` by `.` after the number+name text.

[image]

The full code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}

\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage[english,magyar]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[chapter]{minted}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}                  % http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305387/adding-a-caption-to-a-tcolorbox-tcblisting

\tcbuselibrary{listings,minted,skins,breakable}
\renewcommand*\thelstnumber{\ifnum\value{lstnumber}<10 0\fi\the\value{lstnumber}}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Kódrészlet}
\renewcommand{\listoflistingscaption}{Kódrészletek jegyzéke}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand\fnum@lstlisting{%
  \ifx\lst@@caption\@empty\else\thelstlisting~\fi%
  \lstlistingname}%
\tcbset{
  new/blend into/revlistings/.style={use counter*=lstlisting,list inside=lol,/tcb/code={\appto\tcb@new@colopt{,before title={\tcb@blend@beforetitle{\thetcbcounter~\lstlistingname}}}}},%
}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\let\c@listing\c@lstlisting}
\makeatother

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \newtcblisting[blend into=revlistings]{code}[2]{%
    blend before title code={##1.\ },
    breakable,
    colback=codebg,
    colframe=black!40,
    enhanced,
    listing engine=minted,
    listing only,
    left=5mm,
    overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[black!25] (frame.south west)
      rectangle ([xshift=5mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}},
    listing remove caption=false,
    minted style=colorful,
    minted language=#1,
    minted options={linenos=true,numbersep=3mm,texcl=true,breaklines=true,autogobble=true},
    coltitle=black,
    attach boxed title to bottom center={yshift=-10pt},
    boxed title style={enhanced jigsaw, colback=white, sharp corners, boxrule=0pt},
    #2
  }
}
\definecolor{codebg}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}

\newcommand{\listAref}[1]{\Aref{lst:#1}. kódrészlet}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents\vfill

\newpage

\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
  \begin{code}{swift}{title={Test title}, label={lst:test-code}}

    import Foundation
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

      override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

      }

    }

  \end{code}
\end{otherlanguage}

\listAref{test-code} egy tesztkódot mutat.

\listoflistings\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Kódrészletek jegyzéke}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, it does exactly what I wanted! The `blend before title code={##1.\ },` wasn't necessary for me. I would lie if I say that I understand your _tcbset_. Could you please give an explanation?

Comment: @farkasseb `new/blend into/revlistings` creates an option with is usable as intialization option (this is the `new` branch). Basically, it is a copy of the normal `new/blend into/listings` key you used before. The difference is `before title={\tcb@blend@beforetitle{\thetcbcounter~\lstlistingname}}` - here, the counter and listing name sequence is switched. This stuff is put before every title. The internal macro `\tcb@blend@beforetitle` only adds some decorations like the `:`.

Answer (score 2):

This answer won't completely solve the problem but I hope it helps.

I couldn't find in `tcolorbox` documentation any other option for reversing box number and name than `theorem number and name` option from `theorems` library. But it doesn't work in `tcblistings` and I don't know how to convert a `tcbtheorem` into a `tcblisting`.

So I propose to use `tcblisting` to format the code, but instead of using it as a float, create a new float (`\usepackage{newfloat}`) which will be used to include non floating `tcblisting`s. In this case the caption will correspond to the newfloat type and you can reverse it with [Thorsten Donig](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160720/1952) solution to linked question.

Some code to start working with:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}

\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage[english,magyar]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[chapter]{minted}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}              
\usepackage{newfloat}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[%
    listname={List of My Listings},
    name=MyListing,
    fileext=loml]{mylisting}

\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{reverse}{#2 #1}
\captionsetup{labelformat=reverse}

\tcbuselibrary{listings,minted,skins,breakable}

\newtcblisting{code}[2][]{%
    breakable,
    colback=codebg,
    colframe=black!40,
    enhanced,
    listing engine=minted,
    listing only,
    left=5mm,
    overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[black!25] (frame.south west)
      rectangle ([xshift=5mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}},
    minted style=colorful,
    minted language=#2,
    minted options={linenos=true,numbersep=3mm,texcl=true,breaklines=true,autogobble=true},
    coltitle=black,
    #1
  }


\definecolor{codebg}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}

%\newcommand{\listAref}[1]{\Aref{lst:#1}. kódrészlet}

\begin{document}

\begin{mylisting}
\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
\begin{tcblisting}{
    enhanced,
    breakable, 
    colback=codebg,
    colframe=black!40,
    listing engine=minted,
    listing only,
    left=5mm,
    minted style=colorful,
    minted language=swift,
    minted options={linenos=true, numbersep=3mm, texcl=true,
            breaklines=true, autogobble=true},
    overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[black!25] (frame.south west)
      rectangle ([xshift=5mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}},
}
    import Foundation
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

      override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

      }

    }
\end{tcblisting}
\end{otherlanguage}
\caption{First}
\end{mylisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I chose Thomas's answer because it seemed to be easier to integrate into my thesis (the deadline was quickly approaching). Your solution however is more clean (or at least I can understand the reasoning behind it).